# how to put name and date beside image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pst_h">
                <div class="pr_p col-md-2">
                    <img src="pic" alt="Profile Pic"
                        width="50px" height="50px"/>
                </div>
                <div class="hdr col-md-10">
                    <div class="rec_dtl">
                        <strong>efgh&nbsp;abcd<br/></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rec_dt"> 8/30/14 </div>
                    <div class="post">
                        First of all this query can't work as it is. I already responded about the nee
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/cu06otLa/) 
I want to put the name and date beside the image, but it is showing below the image.

Comment: i just checked your html putting live bootstrap website. it works fine. there is no issue in your html. check bootstrap.css path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **Bootstrap**, the 'Media Object' component serves you for what you are looking for, and would not need to create additional CSS code.

```
<div class="media">

  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="Image"/>
  </a>

  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Name - Date</h4>
    lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
  </div>

</div>
```

A greeting.

EDIT:

See this

http://jsfiddle.net/cu06otLa/2/

Comment: Well then you are overwriting some predefined style Bootstrap class or by cleaning the float yours, should not give that problem...

Answer (score 2):

Your bootstrap classes are correct, and when the screen width is **md** (>= 992px) then the caption will appear by the image. If you expand the fiddle panel you should see this working as you expect

The fiddle panel is quite narrow by default. If you use **col-xs** then the text will display next to the image at all times

```
<div class="row col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="pst_h">
                        <div class="pr_p col-xs-2">
                            <img src="pic" alt="Profile Pic"
                            width="50px" height="50px"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hdr col-xs-10">
                            <div class="rec_dtl">
                                <strong>efgh&nbsp;abcd<br/></strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rec_dt"> 8/30/14 
                     </div>
                    <div class="post">
                       First of all this query can't work as it is. I already responded about the nee                             
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3khsyqog/

Comment: Bootstrap columns have some padding by default, but you could use the "text-right" class on the column containing your image to move it closer to the text

Answer (score 1):

Use the css tag: float.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

dont forget when you use float the clear it when your done with : clear: both;

I've made a fast fix for your problem

new fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/deg4rht5/

HTML

```
<div class="row col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pst_h">
            <div class="hdr col-md-10">
                <img src="pic" alt="Profile Pic" class="float-left" width="50px" height="50px" />
                <div class="rec_dtl float-left"> <strong>efgh&nbsp;abcd<br/></strong>

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="rec_dt float-left">8/30/14</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="pr_p col-md-2">
                <div class="post">First of all this query can't work as it is. I already responded about the nee</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
   .float-left {
        float: left;
    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned your `HTML` code a bit and added `CSS`.

```
.rec_dtl{
    display:inline;
    top:0;
    position:absolute
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cu06otLa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these tags `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CntDK)

```
<figure>
    <p><img src="http://img1.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/b/2/1/91/1091831_stan.gif" alt=""></p>
    <figcaption>image deskription</figcaption>
</figure>

 figure {
    background: #d9dabb; 
    display: block; 
    width: 150px; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0; 
    text-align: center; 
   }
   figure img {
    border: 2px solid #8b8e4b; 
   }
   figure p {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
   }
```